# Q: Upper case/ Lower case search question on Atom editor

Tags: search, atom-editor

I have a question when searching files.

In my project source code, some .c files are named with xxx.c(lower case) and some .c files are names with yyy.C (upper case).

When I search *.c on Atom, I only can get the result with *.c, and I can't get the files with *.C.

How can I get both *.c & *.C results when I search with *.c?

Appreciate for your reply.